# Get the total of variables in active records

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Ok, I have a variable called `$total_bal` that is the answer of a simple equation made from two queries stored in variables `x and y`

**for example**

```
$y = $row->amount_one;
$z = $row->amount_two;

$total_bal = $z + $y;
```

However I have many entries in `amount_one` and `amount_two`.

As I am using codeigniters active records

**I tried**

```
echo $this->db->count_all($total_bal);
```

But this dose not work, any idea of the best way to do this ?

So Im after a way to add all the `$total_bal`up, for more incite into my code see bellow.

```
<?php
if (isset($records)) : foreach ($records as $row) :


    $x = $row->amount_two;
    $y = $row->ammount_one;

   $total_bal = $z + $y;
   ?>

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>amount one</td>
            <td>amount two</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
               <?php echo $x;?>
            </td>

            <td>
               <?php echo $y;?>
            </td>
            <td>
               <?php echo $$total_bal;?>
            </td>
        </tr>

<!--        <tr>-->
<!--            <td>-->
<!--               --><?php //echo $this->db->count_all('$total_bal'); ?>
<!--            </td>-->
<!--        </tr>-->
        </tbody>
    </table>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <h3>You Have No Accounts</h3>
    <h4>Why No Add A Account?</h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How are you setting $row?

Comment: show us your code as well

Comment: Do you want a total for all records or each record? Do you want a sum or a count?

Comment: maybe a `foreach` loop to iterate over everything ?  the information you provided isn't quite clear, do; `var_dump($total_bal);` and share the result with us.

Comment: @andre3wap ok thanks, il update the question with more infomation

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper I want a sum, but of the variables. il expand my question 5 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an accumulator variable. Take for example, a `$grandTotal` variable. You set it to `0` outside the `foreach`, over each iteration of the loop, you add the `$rowTotal` to the `$grandTotal`. Eventually when the loop ends, you have a total value of all row totals.

The benefit to this method is that it doesn't require any additional calls to the database and since you are already looping through the values to display them, accumulating them is minimal processing.

```
<?php if (isset($records)) : ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount One</th>
      <th>Amount Two</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php $grandTotal = 0; ?>
  <?php foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
    <?php 
      // Add field values to get row total
      $rowTotal = $row->amount_one + $row->amount_two;
    ?>
    <?php 
      // Add row total to grand total
      $grandTotal += $rowTotal;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <?php echo $row->amount_one;?>
        </td>

        <td>
           <?php echo $row->amount_two;?>
        </td>
        <td>
           <?php echo $rowTotal;?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><?php $grandTotal; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php else : ?>
  <h3>You Have No Account</h3>
  <h4>Why Not Add An Account?</h4>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hmm, elegant I like it, ill try this out soon and let you know, my code it a lot more extensive than the syntax example i posted so i will try and integrate your answer, but it looks good and promising. +1